# Difference between vertex names and indices in a directed graph

Tags: matrix, graphs-and-networks

A simple digraph `g`:

```
ClearAll[g];
g = Graph[{
   1 -> 2, 1 -> 4, 1 -> 5, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 5, 
   3 -> 1, 3 -> 5, 3 -> 9, 4 -> 2, 4 -> 7,
   5 -> 6, 6 -> 2, 6 -> 8, 7 -> 5, 8 -> 1, 
   8 -> 9, 9 -> 4, 9 -> 7
 }, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
```

This results in an apparently incorrect Adjacency Matrix:

```
AdjacencyMatrix[g]//MatrixForm

{
  {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
  {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
  {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}
 }
```

This adjacency matrix is not what I expected: it seems that many edges are not correctly identified in the adjacency matrix. For instance, in my graph there is no edge from vertex 1 to 3, but I see a $1$ in the (1,3) element of the adjacency matrix. There are several other edges that appear incorrectly mapped in the matrix.

I suspect that the vertices are labeled in a way I do not understand. What am I misinterpreting?

Comment: Not correct *how*? Can you point out where you think it is incorrect, and what you would expect as the correct result?

Comment: @MarcoB: I give a specific set of directed edges and looking at the adjacency matrix, I clearly see that many edges are not correctly given in the adjacency matrix. Just look at my digraph in which there is no edge from vertex 1 to 3, but I see there is `1` in the element `(1,3)` of the matrix. There are several other edges not correctly mapped in the matrix.

Comment: Look at `VertexList[g]` and remember that in general, vertex `4` is not the 4th vertex. Vertex name != vertex index.

Comment: Indeed, if you do `AdjacencyGraph[ the matrix you find ]` you'll see a picture indistinguishable from your original `g`.

Comment: "I suspect that the vertices are labeled in a way I do not understand" - You could also visualize the indices using `Graph[..., VertexLabels -> "Index"]` instead of "Name".

Comment: @MarcoB: Suppose that I only have the set of directed edges represented by vertex names. How am I going to get the intended directed graph with the correctly named vertices?

Comment: @evanb: My intention is to go from the directed graph to Adjacency Matrix, not the other way around. I see that the graph is mapped as expected but not the matrix. How can I get the adjacency matrix that agrees with the digraph?

Comment: The two graphs agree; their labeling do not.

Comment: @evanb: Can you tell me how to represent a given set of directed edges with specific labels in an adjacency matrix format that agrees with the vertex labels in the graph. I just want to have a consistent adjacency matrix (consistent in terms of vertex labels).

Comment: Long-standing gotcha. I get bitten by it from time to time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`AdjacencyMatrix >> Details`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AdjacencyMatrix.html):

> - The vertices $v_i$ are assumed to be in the order given by [VertexList](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexList.html)[$g$].

If an explicit vertex list is *not* provided in the first argument of `Graph`:

[`VertexList >> Details`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexList.html):

> - [VertexList](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexList.html) returns the list of vertices in the order used by the graph $g$.

[`VertexList >> Properties and Relations`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexList.html):

> Vertices are taken in the order they appear in the list of edges:

So... if you provide a vertex list `vlist` in the first argument of `Graph` then `AdjacencyMatrix` rows/columns correspond to the vertices in `vlist`.

```
ClearAll[g1, g2];

g1 = Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 
    1 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 
    3 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 9, 
    4 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 
    6 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 8, 7 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 
    8 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 8 \[DirectedEdge] 9, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 
    9 \[DirectedEdge] 7}, DirectedEdges -> True, 
   VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> Medium];

Row[{g1, MatrixForm[am1 = AdjacencyMatrix[g1]]}]
```

[image]

```
g2 = Graph[
   Range[9], {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 
    1 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 
    3 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 9, 
    4 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 
    6 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 8, 7 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 
    8 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 8 \[DirectedEdge] 9, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 
    9 \[DirectedEdge] 7}, DirectedEdges -> True, 
   VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> Medium];

Row[{g2, MatrixForm[am2 = AdjacencyMatrix[g2]]}]
```

[image]

You can get `am2` from `am1` (and vice versa) using `VertexList` + `Part`:

```
am2 == am1[[Ordering @ VertexList[g1], Ordering @ VertexList[g1]]]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

```
am1 == am2[[VertexList[g1], VertexList[g1]]]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Comment: The list of vertex labels `Range[]` was missing from my graph. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

If your demand is to have an adjacency matrix whose row/column orders are determined by the labels you give, rather than Mathematica's internal representation (given by the order of `VertexList[g]`) you can do

```
o = Ordering[VertexList[g]]
m = AdjacencyMatrix[g] (* Mathematica's ordering *)
y = m[[o,o]] (* your ordering *)
```

The resulting y is

```
{
 {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
 {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
 {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
 {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
 {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}
}
```

which may be what you're looking for?

I just picked `Ordering` because of the 'natural' ordering of your labels as integers.  But you could pick any other ordering `o` and get *a* correct adjacency matrix.

Comment: (But, you may be better off just working with Mathematica's ordering for both the labels, `VertexList[g]`, and the `AdjacencyMatrix[g]`.)

Comment: That is right. This is what I wanted. However, I still think that, for given numerical vertex names, the adjacency matrix should include the correct indices automatically. Unfortunately, it is not the case because vertex names are not always numeric. Therefore, setting the vertex names within `Graph[VertexList[g], directed edges]` solves the problem. Thanks for your time and effort.